# How can I create a non-repeated outside border image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to create a border image for separate divs in the screenshot, yet I can't seem to find a way to do so. Can anyone offer some guidance on how to make these outside border images work?

[image]

Comment: do you have any CSS people could look at? Can't tell what you're after from your question. could you be a little more specific?

Comment: I deleted everything that wasnt working infortunately. Well you see the border on the right of the boxes, that overlap the div? Im trying to recreate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about as close as I can get it. No images required:

```css
.has_tab {
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-left: none;
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 300px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.has_tab:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

/* the important bit... */
.has_tab:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    border-left: none;
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    right: -11px;
}

.has_tab:last-of-type:after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="has_tab">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="has_tab">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="has_tab">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

[Fiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/pLb87c96/3/)

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark one of the answers as correct if it helped

Answer (score 0):

here is how i do it
 first you need to cut this image [image: bg]

and then you can use it as background of after element

```
 <div class="borderd-div"></div>
```

and the css:

```
   .borderd-div{
height: 334px;
width:334px;
border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
position: relative;
}
.borderd-div:after{
content:" ";
 display: block;
   position: absolute;
   width: 20px;
  height: 145px;
 right:-19px;
    top:83px;
  background: url(Djyods1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
   }
```